# Is there a list of environment variables that Spring respects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to understand if there is an exhaustive list of [environment variables that Spring parses during startup.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

For example there is:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USER
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
```

which will be mapped to:

```
spring.datasource.url
spring.datasource.user
spring.datasource.password
```

But I couldn't find any list of exhaustive documentation where all the environment variables Spring recognizes are listed.

What other variables are there ?

Comment: You're probably looking for [this document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-Actually I was only looking for what environment variables I can put for Spring. Not the ones in application.properties.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Actually found it. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables

Comment: It isn't Spring but Spring BOot that adds this feature. Also all properties can be passed as environment properties if you follow the naming convention. So there isn't a list as you can pass everything.